# Lua Macros SAYS 2018-04-03 09:43:01:685 [LUA] ERROR: Cannot load buffer. [string "LuaMacros script"]:44: unexpected symbol near ')'

Tags: lua

Here Is My Code , I would really appreciate it if some one could help me here.
Everytime I run it lure just says 2018-04-03 09:43:01:685 [LUA] ERROR: Cannot load buffer. Which I really don't understand !!! Thanks for the Help!

```
[string "LuaMacros script"]:44: unexpected symbol near ')'
-- assign logical name to macro keyboard

lmc_assign_keyboard('MACROS');



-- define callback for whole device

lmc_set_handler('MACROS',function(button, direction)

  if (direction == 1) then return end  -- ignore down

  if     (button == string.byte('Q')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('W')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('E')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('R')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('T')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('Y')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('U')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('I')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('O')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('P')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('A')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('S')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('D')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('F')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('G')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('H')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('J')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('K')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('L')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('Z')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('X')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('C')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('V')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('B')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('N')) then lmc_spawn("calc")
  if     (button == string.byte('M')) then lmc_spawn("calc")

  else print('Not yet assigned: ' .. button)

  end

  end)
```

The Last Line Is Line 43

Comment: `if button>=string.byte('A') AND button<=string.byte('Z') then lmc_spawn("calc") else print('Not yet assigned: ' .. button) end `

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `if` from the third one by `elseif`.